# Upgrading SSD on Macbook Pro Late 2013

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade

I'm thinking to upgrade the ssd of my macbook pro 15 inc which is late of 2013. I haven't opened up the mac until now. But, as far as I see, ssd of the mac seems different like sliver. I think to buy that one. Isn't it suitable for the mac? I'd like to now the difference whether there is.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013 SSD is not as in the picture of your question. Have a look at [MacBook Pro 15" Retina Display Late 2013 SSD Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2013+SSD+Replacement/23431), to see what the Storage device looks like and how to replace it.

Example Image:

[image: SSD Flash Card]

Also have a look at, [Solid State Drive Upgrades - MacBook Pro with Retina Display 13" & 15" Late 2013, 2014, and 2015](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/macbook-pro-retina-display/2013-2014-2015) from [MacSales.com](https://eshop.macsales.com).

Note that the SSD Upgrade Kit offered by MacSales.com is a reasonably priced and nice option to be able to continue using the original SSD once replaced.

Comment: is there any website to buy the device disk on which your post

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname, I've already included the link in my answer. See: [Solid State Drive Upgrades - MacBook Pro with Retina Display 13" & 15" Late 2013, 2014, and 2015](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/macbook-pro-retina-display/2013-2014-2015)

Comment: im not mentioning of kit and additional website like ebay?

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname, You do not need to buy the kit if you don't want to!  MacSaes.com offers the drive by itself too. As to where else to purchase it, well... you could just Google it.

Comment: You may just buy new NVMe SSD and an adapter to your model.

Comment: @Eugene, RE: "You may just buy new NVMe SSD and an adapter to your model." --  And just how do propose that be done? I seriously doubt there is the room within the **MacBook Pro** to do it or an adapter for this. Regardless one should just use the SSD that was designed for this **Mac** as they are readily available from **OWC**!

Comment: @user3439894 https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000265941706.html nope, I don't think you have to use outdated SSD instead of the modern ones with an adapter

Comment: @Eugene, Let me point out that this question and answer is 5 years old and was an appropriate and accurate answer at the time it was written. Also, to my knowledge there was not an adapter available at that time. That said, I'm not one who'd trust a  $2.36 adapter in my $5000 Mac!

Comment: @user3439894 thanks cap, overpaying is your choice.